# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. How to make sure all views are deleted?

Tags: android, view, viewgroup, removeall

Hi there are plenty of related topic regard this issue are there and I took a look on all of that. I have followed those related answers and I used those suggestion but still I'm getting following error on logcat:

```
06-16 02:54:22.333: W/System.err(20722): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I have a PitchView tht extended from LinearLayout class. `ArrayList<PlayerView> playerList;` holds list of my players and `setupTeamView()` method is responsible to draw class.

User is able to change players. So I'll add chanes to array list (playerList) and then call `setupTeamView()` immediately to redraw the class. There is no problem first time when application is running but when I call `setupTeamView()` method to redraw screen based on new data then application crashes and logcat shows marked line. I have a `clearTeamView()` method that is responsible to clear container of this class. Although it runs but seems doesn't remove its child (`llContainer` in `setupTeamView()` method).

I spent around 10 hours to fix this issue but wasn't successful. I'll be very appreciated if someone tells me what is my problem. Thanks.

```
public class PitchView extends LinearLayout {

   private ArrayList<PlayerView> playerList;

   public void clearTeamView() {
        final LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.team_pitch_view);
        parentLayout.removeAllViews();
    }

    public void setupTeamView() {
        if(playerList == null)
            return;

        // remove all views
        clearTeamView();

        // to count from 1-11 (Number of Players)
        int pointer = 1;

        // Get formation
        ArrayList<Integer> formationArr = Formation.getFormationAsArray(formation);

        // Container to hold other views inside
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
        LinearLayout llContainer = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        llContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        this.addView(llContainer, params);

        // -1.... This is to cover the goalie case, who is always present, and always on his own
        for(int i = -1; i < formationArr.size(); i++) {

            if(i == -1) {
                PlayerView goaller = playerList.get(0);
                goaller.switchStatistics(rightStatsOn);
                goaller.setOnPlayerClickedListener(listener);
                goaller.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                LinearLayout goalieLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                goalieLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                goalieLayout.addView(goaller, params); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR

                llContainer.addView(goalieLayout);
            } else {
                LinearLayout teamMemberLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                teamMemberLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                for (int j = 0; j < formationArr.get(i); j++) {
                    PlayerView player = playerList.get(pointer++);
                    player.switchStatistics(rightStatsOn);
                    player.setOnPlayerClickedListener(listener);
                    player.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                    teamMemberLayout.addView(player, params);
                }

                llContainer.addView(teamMemberLayout);
            }
        }
    }

...
}
```

**======
UPDATE
======**

Thanks to CommonsWare for his suggestion I got good idea but unfortunately, I had same issue. I changed

```
public void clearTeamView() {
            final LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.team_pitch_view);
            parentLayout.removeAllViews();
        }
```

to

```
public void clearTeamView() {
            this.removeAllViews();
        }
```

But I had same issue. I also tried to add llContainer to parentLayout in setupViews but unfortunately, had same result :(

So, I decided to restructure my viewGroup. But I'm still getting same result :(((( Seems it doesn't like me

Any ways, instead creating everything dynamically, I decided to create a layout for my view group like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_play_ground"
        android:id="@+id/ivPlayGround"
        android:contentDescription="@string/general_content_description"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/llContainer">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/llGoalieLayout">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/llDefLayout">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/llMedLayout">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/llFwdLayout">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and changed the class in this form:

```
public class PitchView extends RelativeLayout {

    private static final String TAG = "PitchView";

    private Context mContext;
    public Formation.FORMATION formation;

    private ArrayList<PlayerView> playerList;

    private LinearLayout llContainer;
    private LinearLayout llGoalieLayout;
    private LinearLayout llDefLayout;
    private LinearLayout llMedLayout;
    private LinearLayout llFwdLayout;

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_pinch_view, null);
        addView(view);

        llContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
        llGoalieLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llGoalieLayout);
        llDefLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llDefLayout);
        llMedLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llMedLayout);
        llFwdLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llFwdLayout);

        this.formation = Formation.FORMATION.four_four_two;

        setupTeamView();
    }

    public void clearTeamView() {
        llGoalieLayout.removeAllViews();
        llDefLayout.removeAllViews();
        llMedLayout.removeAllViews();
        llFwdLayout.removeAllViews();

        Log.e(TAG, "goalie child count: " + llGoalieLayout.getChildCount());
        Log.e(TAG, "DEF child count: " + llDefLayout.getChildCount());
        Log.e(TAG, "MED child count: " + llMedLayout.getChildCount());
        Log.e(TAG, "FWD child count: " + llFwdLayout.getChildCount());
    }

    public void setupTeamView() {
        if(playerList == null)
            return;

        // remove all views)
        clearTeamView();

        // Get formation
        ArrayList<Integer> formationArr = Formation.getFormationAsArray(formation);

        // to count from 0-10 (Number of Players)
        int pointer = 0;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

        // 1. This is to cover the goalie case, who is always present, and always on his own
        PlayerView goaller = playerList.get(pointer);
        goaller.switchStatistics(rightStatsOn);
        goaller.setOnPlayerClickedListener(listener);
        goaller.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        llGoalieLayout.addView(goaller, params);

        // 2. This is to cover the defender cases
        for(int i=0; i<formationArr.get(0); i++) {
            PlayerView defender = playerList.get(++pointer);
            defender.switchStatistics(rightStatsOn);
            defender.setOnPlayerClickedListener(listener);
            defender.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            llDefLayout.addView(defender, params); <<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR
        }

        // 3. This is to cover the midfielder cases
        for(int i=0; i<formationArr.get(1); i++) {
            PlayerView midfielder = playerList.get(++pointer);
            midfielder.switchStatistics(rightStatsOn);
            midfielder.setOnPlayerClickedListener(listener);
            midfielder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            llMedLayout.addView(midfielder, params);
        }

        // 4. This is to cover the attacker cases
        for(int i=0; i<formationArr.get(2); i++) {
            PlayerView attacker = playerList.get(++pointer);
            attacker.switchStatistics(rightStatsOn);
            attacker.setOnPlayerClickedListener(listener);
            attacker.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            llFwdLayout.addView(attacker, params);
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "goalie child count: " + llGoalieLayout.getChildCount());
        Log.e(TAG, "DEF child count: " + llDefLayout.getChildCount());
        Log.e(TAG, "MED child count: " + llMedLayout.getChildCount());
        Log.e(TAG, "FWD child count: " + llFwdLayout.getChildCount());
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Same as last time, application works fine in first attempt but will crash when I want to reorganize players on pinch.

This is output of login first run:

```
06-16 17:47:33.326: E/PitchView(24305): goalie child count: 0
06-16 17:47:33.326: E/PitchView(24305): DEF child count: 0
06-16 17:47:33.326: E/PitchView(24305): MED child count: 0
06-16 17:47:33.326: E/PitchView(24305): FWD child count: 0
06-16 17:47:33.346: E/PitchView(24305): goalie child count: 1
06-16 17:47:33.346: E/PitchView(24305): DEF child count: 4
06-16 17:47:33.346: E/PitchView(24305): MED child count: 4
06-16 17:47:33.346: E/PitchView(24305): FWD child count: 2
```

After substitution (formation is same but new object of a player added to playerList and setupTeamView wants to redraw pinch area)

```
06-16 17:50:35.331: E/PitchView(24305): goalie child count: 0
06-16 17:50:35.331: E/PitchView(24305): DEF child count: 0
06-16 17:50:35.331: E/PitchView(24305): MED child count: 0
06-16 17:50:35.331: E/PitchView(24305): FWD child count: 0
06-16 17:52:13.321: E/AndroidRuntime(25088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 17:52:13.321: E/AndroidRuntime(25088): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
06-16 17:52:13.321: E/AndroidRuntime(25088):    at com.allstarxi.view.PitchView.setupTeamView(PitchView.java:169)
```

As you can see, all views are removed but I'm still getting "**You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**"

Answer (score 0):

You are removing all views of `parentLayout`. You did not add `llContainer` to `parentLayout`. You added `llContainer` to `this`. Since `parentLayout` is a child of `this` (since you found it via `findViewById()`), it is not possible for `llContainer` to be a child of `parentLayout`, so removing the children of `parentLayout` will not affect `llContainer`.

Either `llContainer` needs to be a child of `parentLayout`, or you need to remove all views of `this`, or you need to remove `llContainer` from `this` in addition to your current code.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for your suggestion. I got good insight. I spent 5-6 hours on that and checked every possible way but result was same. Is it possible to look at my updates again. Very appreciated :)

Comment: @Hesam: What is line 169 of `PitchView.java`?

Comment: Marked in the code: llDefLayout.addView(defender, params); <<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR

Comment: @Hesam: I have no idea. You will need to see where else you use `playerList` and its elements. You are not populating it in the code above, so perhaps you are using it elsewhere. You might consider dumping `pointer` and using offsets instead (`i+1` in your first loop). And, you can always catch the exception and log who the `defender`'s current parent is.

Answer (score 0):

why you remove all children from **R.id.team_pitch_view**, if all your children have **llContainer** as parent ?

next variant for you:

```
for(PlayerView player : playerList){
((LinearLayout)player.getParent()).removeView(player);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did it but getting same result :( I'm very confused. I'm doing something wrong somewhere that no where!!! Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Your layout suport only one child view, you have to remove all view from it to add another.